# Is it just a coincidence that one cubic foot of water weighs 1000 ounces?

Tags: soft-question, units, density

Is it just a coincidence that one cubic foot of water weighs 1000 ounces (to within 0.1 percent accuracy)?

Comment: Given Ernie's answer, this question might fare better on HSM SE

Comment: Does ice weigh more than water per square foot?

Answer (score 2):

The specific weight of water is 62.43 pounds (avoirdupois) per cubic foot.

62.43 pounds * 16 ounces = 998.88 ounces.  This is a coincidence.

However, what is not a coincidence is the specific weight of water expressed in kilograms per cubic meter.  The density of pure liquid water at 4 degrees centigrade is 1 gram per cubic centimeter, or 1,000 kilograms per cubic meter.

One gram originally was defined to be ["the absolute weight of a volume of pure water equal to the cube of the hundredth part of a metre, and at the temperature of melting ice"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram).

Comment: along the lines of https://xkcd.com/1047/

Comment: ... nor is it a coincidence that a pint of water weighs one pound.  "The world around, a pint's a pound."

Comment: @garyp "The world around, a pint's a pound" - except in the UK, where "a pint of water weighs a pound and a quarter".

Comment: The coincidence resides on $62.43\simeq64=2^6,$ which, together with $16=2^4,$ is intimately connected to $2^{10}\simeq10^3,$ which itself results from $2^7=128\simeq125=5^3.$

Answer (score 0):

Thomas Jefferson noticed that a cubic foot of water weighed 1000 ounces. He came up with a number of such neat correspondences, such that he thought the imperial measurement system was of vast antiquity and carefully thought out, not arbitrary at all.

Answer (score 0):

The ancient weight measurement,the Talent, was defined as the weight of a standardized trade amphora of water, which as it happened coincidentally or intentionally, became both 1000 ounces AND even later 1 cu.ft. of volume.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).